# How Does An Operating System Introduces The C Language To Write The Kernel

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, kernel

Does this introduction occurs at the NTLDR stage because it must be introduce, I mean isn't the Kernel written in C? I thought a computers only "known-before" programming language was Assembly Language that is hard coded at the Microcode of the Processor?

Comment: Your computer *always* runs machine code, not assembly or C. All (native) programming languages get compiled into machine code.

Comment: You are forgetting about cross-compiling.  Not just used in embedded systems, also to bootstrap an operating system.

Answer (score 3):

The first operating systems were all written in assembly. The C Language was created because its first use case was the creation of UNIX. A C compiler was written to handle this code and produce the assembly that the system understands (compiler was written in assembly of course). The effect snowballs from there. We now have a more powerful system to write code so we can of course write better compilers and better software with a more high level approach and let the compiler do the work for us.

As far as Windows is concerned it was a rewrite of an operating system called QDOS which was written in C.

Sidenote: Operating systems still require assembly code to function as there are many hardware independent pieces of information required (for example CR2 read on page fault on x86). Bootloaders and BIOS (older ones) are written in assembly because they are very specific to the hardware and are required to setup things such as interrupts and the stack pointer.

Comment: Windows is not a re-write of QDOS. Windows is NT which was a green field development led by Dave Cutler. No non NT Windows were ever a re-write of QDOS. They were written on top of MS DOS originally, and independent of it latterly.

Comment: Microsoft MS-DOS was a re-write of Tim Paterson's QDOS.  QDOS was written in C.  All Microsoft OS's evolved from - and bear some vestigates of - MS-DOS.  Windows 3.0 and OS/2 were completely separate branches from each other, and from Windows NT.  Windows 98 was the last OS that used 16-bit (DOS) code; Windows XP was the first consumer OS that had all 32-bit (Windows NT) code.

Answer (score 1):

C is a compiled language, as opposed to an interpreted language. C programs as well as the C runtime library are compiled into machine code, so they don't need any kind of runtime environment such as an interpreter or virtual machine to be loaded in order to execute.

The entry point of a compiled program (including a kernel) will call into its runtime library and perform any initialization required before executing the program, but this is all machine code.

Comment: Virtually all programs and all OS's - including the Windows kernel - rely on runtime support.  For example, NT's "Win32" subsystem (csrss.exe) consists of kernel32.dll, user32.dll, gdi32.dll.

Comment: I'm not referring to runtime libraries; those are compiled as well. What I'm saying is that compiled programs don't require an interpreter or virtual machine to be started up in order to execute. ntoskrnl would have its runtime library statically linked.

Comment: @paulsm4: And those DLLs aren't written in C, either. I mean, the logic that they represent was originally, but physically, for those specific files on your hard drive, that was compiled away long ago.